# mostrar texto de span con hover JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

```js
var cont = $("h2#descripcion").text();

function leerSpan() {
  var x = $('span', this).text();
  $('h2').text(x);
}

function volver() {
  var y = $('span', this).text();
  $('h2').text(y);
}

  $("h2").hover(leerSpan, volver);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="contenido">
  <h1>Nuestros servicios</h1>
  <h2 id="descripcion">Sabores únicos para momentos únicos</h2>
  <a id="cupcakes" href="cupcakes.html" title="Cupcakes">
    <span>Variedad única en cupcakes.</span>
    <strong>Cupcakes</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </a>
  <a id="desayunos" href="desayunos.html" title="Desayunos">
    <span>Completísimos desayunos.</span>
    <strong>Desayunos</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </a>
  <a id="tortas" href="tortas.html" title="Tortas">
    <span>Exquisitas tortas de todos los sabores.</span>
    <strong>Tortas</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </a>
  <div id="banner"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

tengo 3 etiquetas span "ocultas", que son las de cupcakes, desayunos y tortas , lo que necesito es que al pasar el mouse (hover) sobre las imagenes , el h2 cambie su contenido por el texto de cada span , intenté creando dos funciones pero no logro que se cambie el texto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que las "imagenes" se encuentran donde dice *Lorem ipsum dolor...* y que el evento `hover` solo es cuando el mouse esta sobre las imágenes o sobre el strong del titulo, puedes simplificarlo usando un `on.mouseenter` y un `on.mouseleave`:

```js
$('span').hide(); //supongamos que estan ocultos

var textoh2 = ''; //guardar #descripcion

$("a").on({
 'mouseenter':function(){ //sobre
  textoh2 = $('h2').text();
  var txt =  $(this).find('span').text();
  $('h2').text(txt);
 },
 'mouseleave':function(){ //alejado
  $('h2').text(textoh2);
 }
});
```

```css
a{
  display:inline-block; /*solo demostrativo*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido">
  <h1>Nuestros servicios</h1>
  
  <h2 id="descripcion">Sabores únicos para momentos únicos</h2>
  
  <a id="cupcakes" href="cupcakes.html" title="Cupcakes">
    <span>Variedad única en cupcakes.</span>
    <strong>Cupcakes</strong><br> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxbzzxRWP-N-Kb8X4ZY_mM8lhl-dN2ke5lFB_TvR0ggylo9lvw" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <a id="desayunos" href="desayunos.html" title="Desayunos">
    <span>Completísimos desayunos.</span><br>
    <strong>Desayunos</strong><br><img src="https://www.infobae.com/new-resizer/oAV37GUJPvHGRwE1DLT-Y2Zq6Zk=/600x0/filters:quality(100)/s3.amazonaws.com/arc-wordpress-client-uploads/infobae-wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/01155235/iStock-502808838.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <a id="tortas" href="tortas.html" title="Tortas">
    <span>Exquisitas tortas de todos los sabores.</span><br>
    <strong>Tortas</strong><br><img src="http://food.fnr.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2014/3/15/0/GI1607H_Tortas-Ahogadas_s4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.462.suffix/1401373824370.jpeg" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <div id="banner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender lo que buscas, pero tu código es raro y confuso. Esto es nuevo a ver si te sirve.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="contenido">
         <h1>Nuestros servicios</h1>
         <h2 id="descripcion">Sabores únicos para momentos únicos</h2>
         <a id="cupcakes" href="cupcakes.html" title="Cupcakes">
          <span>Variedad única en cupcakes.</span>
          <strong>Cupcakes</strong>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         </a>
         <a id="desayunos" href="desayunos.html" title="Desayunos">
          <span>Completísimos desayunos.</span>
          <strong>Desayunos</strong>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         </a>
         <a id="tortas" href="tortas.html" title="Tortas">
          <span>Exquisitas tortas de todos los sabores.</span>
          <strong>Tortas</strong>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         </a>
         <div id="banner"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $contenido = "";
            $("#cupcakes").hover(function () {
                $contenido =  $(this).find('span').text();
                $("#descripcion").text($contenido);
            });
            $("#desayunos").hover(function () {
                $contenido =  $(this).find('span').text();
                $("#descripcion").text($contenido);
            });
            $("#tortas").hover(function () {
                $contenido =  $(this).find('span').text();
                $("#descripcion").text($contenido);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```